# Reference an Excel Column based on an Excel cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel how can I create a cell function which does the following ...

1. If cell C1 contains the value 6, I want cell B1 to be the contents of cell M1,
2. If cell C1 contains the value 7, I want cell B1 to be the contents of cell N1

and so forth, increasing by one column (M,N,O...) at a time.

I've tried with the functions INDEX, IF , MATCH and, LOOKUP .

Answer (score 3):

Use `INDEX` and simple math:

```
=INDEX(1:1,C1+7)
```